# PostgreSQL JSON manipulations

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-11

```
with t as (

SELECT '{
  "tf": {
    "column_value_0": {
      "column": "column_0",
      "key": "&",
      "texts": [
        "forbid",
        "god"
      ]
    },
    "column_value_1": {
      "column": "column_1",
      "key": "!",
      "texts": [
        "foo",
        "red"
      ]
    }, "query_group" : "(column_0) & (column_1)"
  }
}' :: json as p
), h as (
SELECT f.key,f.value ->> 'column' as column  ,format('%s <-> %s', f.value ->> 'column'
                                 , (SELECT string_agg(' (' || k.value || ') ', f.value ->> 'key') 
                                    FROM json_array_elements_text(f.value -> 'texts') k)
                                 ) as final

FROM t, json_each(p -> 'tf') f
WHERE f.key not in ('query_group')
)
SELECT * FROM h
```

Output

```
      key        column         final       
column_value_0  column_0 column_0 <->  (forbid) & (god) 
column_value_1  column_1 column_1 <->  (foo) ! (red)
```

Now I'd like to know whether there is a way of forming my output based on the "query_group".

the expected output is (the query_group is dynamic)

```
(column_0 <->  (forbid) & (god)) & (column_1 <->  (foo) ! (red))
```

Comment: I am actually using 11. But I didn't find the version to tag. Sorry should have mentioned the version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought you would give me some hint to go on. :)